# Spreading values on a bar chart with plotly

Tags: python, python-2.7, charts, bar-chart, plotly

I've got this list of numbers:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.06973765202658326, 0.0759476951525558, 0.09813542688910697, 0.10382657209692146, 0.11627906976744186, 0.12999675008124797, 0.15083990401097017, 0.15699535052231145, 0.1582487142291969, 0.16269605108256963, 0.17534585680947898, 0.17575928008998876, 0.1797698945349952, 0.19140660888739167, 0.1957585644371941, 0.19736565837544265, 0.21997813082909887, 0.22955485152768082, 0.24996957973509318, 0.29229031347077095, 0.31290263206331675, 0.32396867885822933, 0.3546099290780142, 0.3868519865218288, 0.46728971962616817, 0.48625583010816714, 0.4941864275695728, 0.5247165920267484, 0.5524861878453038, 0.564214589168688, 0.6127450980392157, 0.641025641025641, 0.6548963526282728, 0.7150582862636703, 0.823158183564275, 0.9224003861210919, 0.9253497118428529, 1.0174746597810627, 1.1462377518949898, 1.2255992248732304, 1.3000416806982482, 1.398793198025233, 1.3995903637959621, 1.4131338320864506, 1.592256254439621, 1.6498929836480547, 1.9240644218177165, 2.0467034604427172, 2.0581059831456088, 2.2849018651470887, 2.321192247101101, 2.478639485813531, 2.502272275797079, 3.530109015879148, 4.062209258467651, 6.116463053656961, 7.042445376777638, 7.177446333392399, 7.997926085414144, 8.793098189482022, 13.318221845340986, 14.199853408258, 25.417144730372073, 32.31529306085785, 53.557772100818454]
```

And I want to build a bar chart using plotly so I did this:

```
import plotly.offline as po
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Layout
import plotly.graph_objs as go
po.offline.init_notebook_mode()

distribution = go.Histogram(
    x=my_list,
    xbins=dict(
        size=1
    )
)
data = [distribution]
layout = go.Layout(
    title="Distribution",
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
po.iplot(fig)
```

I obtain a chart like:
[image: My chart]

But when I change the size of xbins my chart doesn't change. How can I spread my first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can simply use: (within the `layout = ( )`)

```
xaxis = dict(tickvals = [ 0, 0.1, 2, 30, 40, 50 ])
```

Or something of the sort, to get the varied definition in your x-axis you are looking for.

I am not too familiar with plotly, but this seems to me like it should at least be a start to brute force the axis in the right direction.